# How to implement searchview in activity (actionbar) when listview exists in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am developing an application in which searchview is in main activity's action bar. And in the main activity there are 3 fragments. There is a listview in each fragment. The problem is that how can I sort fragment's list item when searchview is implemented in activity's action bar.

I am using simple cursor adapter and listview having custom row in which there are textview and imageview.

[image]

This is the code of searchview in activity

```
SearchManager SManager =  (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchViewAction = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
    searchViewAction.setSearchableInfo(SManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

            android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            System.out.println("on text chnge text: "+newText);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            System.out.println("on query submit: "+query);
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchViewAction.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
```

And the code of fragment is

```
Cursor mCursor = getContacts();
getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);



c_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contact_item, mCursor,
        new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                , ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},

        new int[]{R.id.username1, R.id.ivuserpicicon1});



    if (c_adapter.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(c_adapter);
    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

How can I implement searchview. I need little guidance.

Comment: what you have tried so far.

Comment: If this is what you application looks like right now, make sure you use AppCompat and target 22 so users will being able to view this(as close as they can) in Material Design.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.I have search view in the main activity and it contains a view pager which is populated through Fragments by using FragmentStatePagerAdapter .List view is contained in the fragments .I need to filter the list  view of fragment of the active tab usingSearch view in the main activity .Have you solved your problem?Please help me to resolve the issue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity to fragment communication is fairly simple when compared to fragment to activity communication. You can check the following link for both the types of communication

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

In your activity you can get an instance of your fragment containing the ListView and invoke all search and sort operations.

Assuming that you have added

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

for your search menu item in your menu layout file, in the onCreateOptionsMenu of your activity you can add

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.your_search_menu_item);
    SearchView actionSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    actionSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    actionSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(//Set up your OnQueryTextListener here);
```

In the onQueryTextChange method of the OnQueryTextListener, you can invoke your fragments methods for search and sort.